# Why does my discord.py bot not respond to the on_message event?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot for a Minecraft server's discord. I have an on_member_join event and an on_message event below it. The on_member_join works perfectly, but when I send a message in the discord server, nothing inside the on_message event happens. Here is my code, if someone has a possible solution I would really appreciate it.

```
import discord
import os
import datetime

intents = discord.Intents(members = True, guilds = True)
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)
yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
joinList = []

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  global verify
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  await client.get_channel(809271484475506698).send('Welcome, <@' + str(member.id) + '>! Please enter your main Minecraft username into this channel.')
  joinList.append(str(member.name))
  print(joinList)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  print('test')

  print(joinList)
  messages = await client.get_channel(809256065387462696).history(after = yesterday).flatten()

  if str(message.author.name) in joinList:
    for i in range(len(messages)):
      if message.content in str(messages[i]):
        print('success!')
        return

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Does the `print('test')` also not work?

Comment: No, I don't get anything in the console after sending messages

Comment: Does the bot have full access to that channel?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the beginning of your program, with the rest of your imports: `from discord.utils import get`. You need to include this, because you're using `client.get_channel`, which requires you to import `get` first.

Comment: I added that, but it's underlined in green and it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Gabe Palmer If it's highlighting it in green, that means you don't have the library downloaded. You can download it by running this in your command line: `pip install DiscordUtils`

Comment: where do I put that?

Comment: You run it in your command line, also known as your terminal.

Comment: It did nothing, I'm using repl.it if that helps at all

Comment: also, the client.getchannel works as it's supposed to, so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: @GabePalmer Oh, yes. That's very different, then. I haven't used repl.it before. So read [this](https://docs.repl.it/repls/packages) on how you can add a package.

Comment: It does? Well, then I'm not sure how to help you.

Comment: 1. to use get or get_channel or whatever you don't have to import it seperately (especially not for get_channel because it is another function in another section) 2. Discord Utils are by standard installed with discord.py